# 'create-react-app' or 'express react engine' which one should I use?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm new to react js and I'm little bit confused with it. However I've done a simple login app using create-react-app [nodejs as back end] [the api way]. Also there are view engine packages available in npm for server side rendering. So, my question is, which one is better ?

Comment: create-react-app is a cli tool for creating react app while express-react-engine is used for server side rendering

Comment: Hi @user93, thanks for the reply. yes,you are correct. I'm asking, which one is better ?